# Dynamically create string using return value from blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, objective-c-blocks

So I'm trying to dynamically build a string and I'd really like all the code which builds this string to live in a block passed as a parameter to the `stringWithFormat` method. The following code example should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    NSString * deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", ^NSString*(void){

        NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale];

    }];
```

The expected output of this would be something like...

```
Device Language: en_GB
```

However, the output I'm getting from this method actually returns the `description` of the NSGlobalBlock method, e.g.

```
Device Language: <__NSGlobalBlock__:0x30a35c>
```

Is this because i'm not using the correct placeholder in the string, or failing to declare that the block returns an `NSString` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you pass the block itself as argument to `stringWithFormat:`, 
instead of the result of *calling* the block:

```
NSString * deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", ^NSString*(void){

    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                         value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale];

}()];
```

Note that you can achieve a similar result with a ["compound statement expression"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)
instead of a block:

```
NSString * deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", ({

    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                         value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale];

})];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'd never come across compound statement expressions before, this looks very useful!

Comment: In the first case it is enough to write [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", ^{...}()];

Comment: That makes me feel better, all I missed were the final () to actually execute the block!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question!

The problem is in the `stringWithFormat:`. As it's processing it's format string, when it reaches the `%@`, it finds the object argument, calls `-description` on it and adds the object's description to its output. The description in this case is `<__NSGlobalBlock__:0x30a35c>`

You can get around this by doing:

```
NSString*(^userLanguage)(void) = ^(void) {
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                                             value:[locale localeIdentifier]];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale];

};
NSString *language = userLanguage();
NSString * deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", language];
```

But of course you don't need the block now, so you can just do this:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                                         value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
NSString *userLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale];;
NSString * deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Language: %@", userLanguage];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It makes sense however I was trying to keep everything contained within the one statement for clean code so I'm going to accept Martin's answer, but this is equally valid. Your explanation of exactly why it was failing was very useful. Wish i could accept both answers!

Comment: `for clean code` is arguable :P I'd prefer a method call over a compound statement in most cases.

Comment: You're probably right, I just liked the idea that one can see everything that goes into construction of the string, within the method that creates the string (as it were) but i'm really just experimenting with blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the block object to `stringWithFormat`: so you are printing the description. As in @MartinR Answer. 
An easier management to your blocks would be if you recode it like this.

```
// first you declare a block like this, to retain it or pass it multiple times
typedef NSString* (^MyBlock)(void);

       MyBlock block = ^{
        NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                                                 value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
                                   // print the local id
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", language, locale.localeIdentifier];
    }; 

// Now pass it to stringWithFormat:
NSString *deviceLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"device language: %@", block()];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten you're meant to `typedef` significant blocks like this.

Comment: @Sammio2, also see I am printing locale.localeIdentifier instead of locale to get the desired results

Comment: I did notice actually, thanks. I've since realised that the actual information i was looking for is available using this simple code `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` making this whole question null and void, but it's taught me something about blocks!